# How to extract data for non-fixed string

Tags: lua, pattern-matching, design-patterns, string-matching

I have some [`magnet`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_uri) links being submitted as string in **Lua**. These magnets normally are of the format:

```
magnet:?xt=<hashing>&xl=<size>&dn=<name>
```

but with differences in the clients the magnets can also be generated as:

```
magnet:?xl=<size>&xt=<hashing>&dn=<name>
```

From this type of string, I want to fetch the data after **`xl=`**(which is pure number) and after **`xt=`** which consists of `%w` and `:`(where `%w` is alphanumeric match).

Currently I am using two separate statements to fetch these values. Can this be achieved in a single statement/`string.find()`?

```
sInput = "magnet:?xt=urn:tree:tiger:ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890ABC&xl=1234567890123456789&dn=This+Is+The+Name+Of+File.EXT"
local _, _, sHash = sInput:find( "xt=([%w%:]+)" )
local _, _, iSize = sInput:find( "xl=(%d+)" )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd be better off collecting all values into a table:

```
local sInput="magnet:?xt=<hashing>&xl=<size>&dn=<name>"
local s=sInput:match("%?(.*)$").."&"
local t={}
for k,v in s:gmatch("(%w+)=(.-)&") do
        t[k]=v
end
```

If you want to restrict to the keys starting with `x` then use `gmatch("(x%w+)=(.-)&")`. If you know that `xt` and `xl` are never the last item in the list, you can simply do:

```
for k,v in sInput:gmatch("(x%w+)=(.-)&") do
```

Comment: FYI: he is one of the authors of Lua :)